# The compiler show error message when using ProjectExplorer in Eclipse Kpler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I use the following code in Kepler:

```java
ProjectExplorer projExplorer = (ProjectExplorer) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
getActivePage().findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
```

And I have added org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.jar, however, when I compile my project, it shows an error message:

```
The type org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
```

files

Comment: Are you stating your dependency on the plug-in that contains `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator`?

Comment: I tried, but I could add the org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator to the dependencies, I can only add org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources, it was strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CommonNavigator` is in the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator` plugin so add that to your plugin's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you check that jar @ docjar : http://docjar.com/jar_detail/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.3.100.I20080606-1300.jar.html, you'll find that CommonNavigator is not there.

You probably need this one: http://docjar.com/jar_detail/org.eclipse.ui.navigator_3.3.100.I20080606-1300.jar.html